# Is there a way to add a Subversion section to the right click menu for TextMate?

Tags: svn, textmate

I'd like to be able to click on a file to revert it, or check in a directory, etc.  It would be much more convenient to have these available from the right click menu.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this?

**ProjectPlus**

ProjectPlus is a plug-in for TextMate which extends the functionality of project-related features.

Feature list:
* SCM status badges:
* Support for SVN, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Svk
* Displayed in the project file list and the window proxy icon

http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I'd recommend the [SVNMate bundle](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/07/30/svnmate-update-for-subversion-15) though.